# Entitlements.plist error when trying to build non ad-hoc versions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

I searched all around for an answer but no luck....

I successfully built an ad-hoc version of this app, but now when i try to build for debug, release, or regular distribution i get the build error:

"CodeSign error: The entitlements file '/Users/Dropbox/myApp/Entitlements.plist' is missing"

the thing is 
a) The entitlements.plist file is sitting right there in the resources folder 
b) That isn't even the correct path to the xcode project folder. 
c) I removed the key from the project settings> build> code signing entitlements, so why is it even looking for the entitlements.plist?

what is going on?? How can I get xcode to stop trying to find the entitlements file, I know it isnt even needed for the anything other than ad-hoc builds.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks all, i think i figured it out. Hopefully this will help anyone else who runs into this:

I ended up going into 'targets' and right-clicking 'get info' (or alternatively Project>Edit Active Target ) and the entitlement.plist is listed in the build tab there as well. I removed it there and in the project settings and issue solved.

Again, thanks all :)

Answer (score 5):

In my case what really helped out was :
 1. Click the project just above the target. 
 2. Goto build settings
 3. Change the code signing entity to the correct one .
[image]

Answer (score 4):

99% you don't need Entitlements.plist.  it's just a bad error message (possibly the worst and most misleading in all of Xcode)

Instead, re-download your provisioning profile.

Comment: This was what I needed as well, except I then got an error saying that the bundle identifier "[string]" didn't match "[identical string]", but fixed this by cleaning the project and quiting and restarting XCode, as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12450184/3408

Answer (score 3):

Just a suggestion.
Yes, removing Entitlements.plist from settings works. But most probably the path listed in the settings has changed, as it is an absolute path.

In my case it folder name had changed but framework was looking for the file in old path.

Answer (score 0):

A couple ideas:

1. Make sure that the build settings you are editing is the one for the build configuration you are building with.
2. I have found what works for me is to toggle the "get-task-allow" boolean when I build for development (true for development builds, false for ad-hoc).

I am pretty sure that if you have an entitlements plist in your project, it will try to use that unless another one is specified, so you might be able to have two entitlements plists and have your ad-hoc configuration point to one and your development configuration point to the other.

Comment: Saw a bunch of posts about that... "the get-task-allow" key isn't used anymore aparently.

Answer (score 0):

Tap on Targets => Summary => Entitlements => Check out "Use Entitlements File". This worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted code signing entitlements entry from build setting, after that my error gone and i am able to make archive without any issue.if you have no file entitlement.plist you should delete entry from build setting.