# Code Sign error: Application Identifier 'com.reapptive.Floors2Go' which doesn't match the current setting 'com.reapptive.Floors2Go'

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning

I updated my provisioning profile to include some more devices for Ad-Hoc testing,I added this new profile and removed the old and now I am getting this error:

> Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'Floors2Go' specifies the
>   Application Identifier 'com.reapptive.Floors2Go' which doesn't match
>   the current setting 'com.reapptive.Floors2Go'

Which if you look they are both exactly the same, I have removed, re-added a new profile, deleted and re-entered the bundle name in my plist and for the life of me I cant figure this out.

I have also tried cleaning all and rebuild but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in Xcode GM Seed, I had to kill Xcode and reopen it every time I change a profile.

Comment: I had to Clean, remove the profile, set everything to "Don't code sign," relaunch Xcode and re-add the profile and set code signing again before it worked. Probably not all necessary, but I'll treat it like voodoo until I know what the specific steps are.

Comment: Same here, still buggy with XCode 4.5.1.

Comment: I had to double check and reassign all my Debug & Release Code Signing Identities (between my Project-level settings and my Target-level settings). One of the profiles I had added a device to was stale, but still somehow associated with the Release setting.

Comment: @TimR. your solutions seems to be working.. Atleast to me killing xcode doesn't worked for me.

Comment: Still buggy on 4.6.1.
This provisioning adventure has gone on way to long

Comment: and on 4.6.2. I'm sick of this.

Answer (score 19):

I also had this problem while trying to replace a dev provisioning profile with an updated version.  Looks like a bug.

Running XCode clean, then setting the code signing identity (for dev, in my case) to "don't code sign", then setting the code sign identity back to the relevant development provisioning profile resolved the build error.

Comment: Set don't sign, build, Set sign, build. Marvelous!

Answer (score 7):

In Xcode (I am using 4.5.2) > Build Settings > Code Signing section:

1. Change everything to `Don't Code Sign`
2. Change individual setting to appropriate developer/distribution profiles.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, deleting a duplicate and invalid certificate in keychain fixed this problem..

Answer (score 0):

It should be problem with the Application Identifier in the plist file.Check that. Did you install the new Provisioning Profile?

Comment: hi, i have checked the application identifier and it is correct and yes i installed the new provisioning profile but still nothing. what i dont understand is they are both the same when it is showing me the error

Comment: ok cool check the codesign identity in the project and targets individually. Check for debug,release also in the code sign identity

Answer (score 0):

- 1- Clean (Product --> Clean)
- 2- Remove Prov. Profile (Window --> Organizer ) remove unused and expired prov. profile
- 3- Set everything to dont code sign in your project and target (press on your project under build settings under code sign set everything to dont code sign and do it again on you target)
- 4- Relaunch Xcode
- 5- Re-add prov. profile
- 6- Go to code sign again and set them to your prov. profile.
- 7- Do step 6 again for code sign in your target.
  If it didnt work try to make the next step
- 8- Any iOS SDK under debug set it to iPhone or iPad developer under automatic profile selector.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all Prov. Profile from Organizer
2. From Menu Select **Editor** -> **Refresh From Developer Center**
3. Enter your apple id and password and wait
4. Go to **Buit Settings** of App select **development profile** for **debug** and **ad-Hoc profile** for **release**

**Note** It is Advice to create two different profile for development and testing

- For Development - > Create Development Profile -> Use
- For Distribution -> Create Ad Hoc Profile