# Xcode Provisioning: Application Identifier doesn't match even though they are the same

Tags: xcode, provisioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code Sign error: Application Identifier ‘com.reapptive.Floors2Go’ which doesn’t match the current setting ‘com.reapptive.Floors2Go’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406159/code-sign-error-application-identifier-com-reapptive-floors2go-which-doesnt)

`Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'Provisioning Profile Name' specifies the Application Identifier 'com.company.appname' which doesn't match the current setting 'com.company.appname'`

--Note that the "Application Identifier" and "current setting" are character-for-character identical.

I recently replaced an old provisioning profile in the Organizer with a newer version of the profile to add more devices. The previous profile worked fine, and I made sure to go into the Code Signing Identity section of the project settings and change it to use the new profile. What could cause this?

Answer (score 4):

Check with your keychain listings..
There might be duplicate profiles as you have already installed new one over older one.
In cas you found duplicate profiles, remove older one and remove your "DerivedData" (in case of xcode 4.3/ xcode 4.5) or "Build" folder and then set profile settings for your target and try to rebuild.

Duplication of same profile might be creating causing while you are selecting profile.

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution in a question this was a duplicate of, it turned out to be a bug in Xcode. Voting to close this as a duplicate.